# How to include mailto link within model error message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the correct syntax to add mailto to this ASP.NET MVC3 code.  This doesn't work and neither does using double-quotes:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "We could not locate the email address you entered.  Please check the email address.  If you believe it is correct, please contact us by sending an email to <a href='mailto:support@abc.com'>Support</a> from the email address you are attempting to use.");
```

Comment: What you mean "doesn't work"? What HTML you get?

Comment: This is what is displayed in the browser:  an email to <a href='mailto:support@abc.com'>Support</a>

Comment: So this means the text is being encoded server side.. fear there's not much you can do apart maybe adding global JavaScript to convert it to actual link. If feasible let me know and I'll come with sample.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that good at Razor but this can solve your problem for now

```
@Html.Raw(Html.ValidationSummary().ToString().Replace("[mailto]", "<a href='mailto:support@abc.com'>Support</a>"))
```

and your message will contain this

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "We could not locate the email address you entered.  Please
check the email address.  If you believe it is correct, please contact us by sending an 
email to [mailto] from the email address you are attempting to use.");
```

The link is now added in the view instead from the server/controller, replacing your `[mailto]` with actual link and calling `Html.Raw` to render the html in the browser

Answer (score 0):

try to use

add this NamesPace :`Using System.Text`

```
    StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder ();
    s.Append(We could not locate the email address you entered.  Please check the email address.  If you believe it is correct, please contact us by sending an email to ");
    s.Append("<a href='mailto:support@abc.com'>Support</a>");
    s.Append("from the email address you are attempting to use.");
    ModelState.AddModelError("", s.ToString());
```